# How to delete entire row if my specified column value starts with '1'

Tags: r

I have a dataset:

```
yearID  teamID  lgID  playerID   salary
 1985    BAL     AL   murraed02  1472819
 1985    BAL     AL   lynnfr01   1090000
 1985    BAL     AL   ripkeca01  800000
 1985    BAL     AL   lacyle01   725000
 1985    BAL     AL   flanami01  641667
 1985    BAL     AL   boddimi01  625000
 1985    BAL     AL   stewasa01  581250
```

I'd like to delete an entire row if the `salary` column value starts with '1'.

For instance, if the `salary` column value is `12240`, I'd like to remove the row.

Comment: Try: `x  <- x[substr(x$salary, 1, 1) == 1,]`

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You're asking us to solve a problem but you don't show evidence of trying to solve it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Actually, I had a hard time to figure out what the answer of this question might be, and did a lot of effort to solve it. However, I forgot to mention it. I thought the question should be concise as possible. Next time, I will elaborate if I post another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fun idea with math,

```
df[df$salary / 10^(nchar(df$salary)) >= 0.2,]

#  yearID teamID lgID  playerID salary
#3   1985    BAL   AL ripkeca01 800000
#4   1985    BAL   AL  lacyle01 725000
#5   1985    BAL   AL flanami01 641667
#6   1985    BAL   AL boddimi01 625000
#7   1985    BAL   AL stewasa01 581250
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
tibble(x = c(123, 4232, 312, 321)) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("^1", x))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df[!stringr::str_extract(df$salary, "\\d{1}")==1,]

  yearID teamID lgID  playerID salary
3   1985    BAL   AL ripkeca01 800000
4   1985    BAL   AL  lacyle01 725000
5   1985    BAL   AL flanami01 641667
6   1985    BAL   AL boddimi01 625000
7   1985    BAL   AL stewasa01 581250
```